# Unable to login via Keycloak. 404 on sso/login after logout

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I use Keycloak in my Spring Boot application and I have my custom logout endpoint

```
    @GetMapping("/logout")
    public void logout(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
        request.logout();
    }
```

When I request it than I am succefully logout from my application. `KEYCLOAK_ADAPTER_STATE` cookie is reset.

But when I want to login again I have 404 on `/sso/login` endpoint.

The only way I can login again is to clean all other cookies.

So should I in my `/logout` endpoint clean all other cookies or there is more appropriate way to solve the problem?